# Is there a way to get the recursive and iterative functions for Fibonacci working in a 'for' loop?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have these pieces of codes and they are all working with the exception of #1) the Fibonacci case. I pretty much have everything syntax-wise, but the output is giving me just the few lines from the main.cpp file. If I remove the Fibonacci section (case #1), the other 3 cases run just fine.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "rec_fun.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() 
{
      cout<<"#1)"<<endl;
      int n1 = 1;
      cout<<"Fibonacci"<<endl;
     printf("%5c   %10s   %10s   %10s   %10s", 'n', "Recursive", "time_r(s)", "Iterative", "time_i(s)");

    
     int i;
     savitch2::recursion recur;

     for (i = 1; i < 50; i++)
     {
            high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
           int fibR = recur.fib_recursion(i);
            high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << fixed;
            duration<float> time_span = endTime - startTime;


            high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
           int fibI = recur.fib_iterative(i);
            high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << fixed;
            duration<float> time_span2 = endTime2 - startTime2;

           
           printf("%5d"   "%10d"   "%10f"   "%10d"   "%10f", i, fibR, time_span.count(),fibI, time_span2.count());
           //recur.fib_recursion(i);// Replace with call to your function.
           //recur.fib_iterative(i);
                        
     }
    

     //std::cout << fixed;
     //std::cout << "It took " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
     //std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

rec_fun.cpp :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "rec_fun.h"
#include <string>

using namespace savitch2;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int recursion::fib_iterative(int n) {
    if(n == 1 || n == 2)
        return 1;
    int A[2][2] = { { 1, 1 },{ 1, 0 } };
    int B[2][2] = { { 1, 1 },{ 1, 0 } };
    int temp[2][2];
    while (n >= 2) {
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
             for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                 temp[i][k] = 0;
                 for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                     temp[i][k] += A[i][j] * B[j][k];
              }
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
             for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                 B[i][j] = temp[i][j];
         n--;
    }
    return B[0][1];
}

int recursion::fib_recursion(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib_recursion(n-1) + fib_recursion(n-2);
}
```

rec_fun.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace savitch2
{
    class recursion
    {
        public:
            int fib_iterative(int n);
            int fib_recursion(int n);
        private:
            int ones;
            int tens;
            string s;

    };
}
```

Output for Fibonacci should be this :

```
Fibonacci
   n     Recursive   time_r(s)      Iterative   time_i(s)
   1             1    0.000000              1    0.000000
   2             1    0.000000              1    0.000000
   3             2    0.000000              2    0.000000
   4             3    0.000000              3    0.000001
. . .
  43     433494437    2.015535      433494437    0.000002
  44     701408733    3.270357      701408733    0.000002
  45    1134903170    5.258732     1134903170    0.000002
```

Output I am getting:

```
#1)
Fibonacci
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] if most of the code is working then remove it and just leave the problematic part. Also the body of your question doesn't seem to bear any relation to the title?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: I have left the problematic part only.